# Group array of objects by id in javascript

Tags: javascript

There are three objects like this.

```
var Object1 = [
    {
        "_id": "62397fd1c517e11e05935cc7",
        "nickname": "uknowTest2",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-22T07:50:41.769Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "623824ccd1164bb8d9cc2521",
        "nickname": "qnvvzjrh",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-21T07:10:04.888Z",
        "animalCount": 1
    }
];

var Object2 = [
    {
        "_id": "62397fd1c517e11e05935cc7",
        "data": 36
    },
    {
        "_id": "623824ccd1164bb8d9cc2521",
        "data": 542717
    }
];

var Object3 = [
    {
        "_id": "62397fd1c517e11e05935cc7",
        "data2": 133111
    },
    {
        "_id": "623824ccd1164bb8d9cc2521",
        "data2": 540517
    }
];
```

And I want to group them like this:

```
var result = [
    {   
        "_id": "62397fd1c517e11e05935cc7",
        "data": 36,
        "data2": 133111,
        "nickname": "uknowTest2",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-22T07:50:41.769Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "623824ccd1164bb8d9cc2521",
        "data": 542717,
        "data2": 540517,
        "nickname": "qnvvzjrh",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-21T07:10:04.888Z",
        "animalCount": 1
    }
];
```

Several similar types of data are generated.
I'm not sure what to do.
Using object.assign doesn't seem to be the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is taking time complexity of `O(n)`

**Here you go:**

```
const allObj = [...Object1, ...Object2, ...Object3];

const preResult = {};
allObj.forEach((obj)=> {
    preResult[obj._id] = preResult[obj._id] ? {...preResult[obj._id], ...obj} : obj;
})

const result = Object.values(preResult)
console.log(result)
```

**Explaination:**

1. `allObj`  is the concatenation of all objects
2. `allObj.forEach` is looping through all elements (sub objects)
3. Using ternary operator to assign the value
4. If `obj._id` (key) already exist in `preResult`, then assign `{...preResult[obj._id], ...obj}` (which is concat of existed value and new value)
5. Else assign new value `obj`
6. preResult is pair of obj._id (key) and merged-object (values)
7. final result is the only values of `preResult`

Code Snippet:

```js
var Object1 = [
    {
        "_id": "62397fd1c517e11e05935cc7",
        "nickname": "uknowTest2",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-22T07:50:41.769Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "623824ccd1164bb8d9cc2521",
        "nickname": "qnvvzjrh",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-21T07:10:04.888Z",
        "animalCount": 1
    }
];

var Object2 = [
    {
        "_id": "62397fd1c517e11e05935cc7",
        "data": 36
    },
    {
        "_id": "623824ccd1164bb8d9cc2521",
        "data": 542717
    }
];

var Object3 = [
    {
        "_id": "62397fd1c517e11e05935cc7",
        "data2": 133111
    },
    {
        "_id": "623824ccd1164bb8d9cc2521",
        "data2": 540517
    }
];

const allObj = [...Object1, ...Object2, ...Object3];

const preResult = {};
allObj.forEach((obj)=> {
    preResult[obj._id] = preResult[obj._id] ? {...preResult[obj._id], ...obj} : obj;
})

// console.log(preResult)

const result = Object.values(preResult)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Definitely, this is a very optimised solution.

Comment: Could you explain your code as well. Thank you

Comment: Received fairly high quality answers. thank you.

Comment: @Nikkkshit
1.  `allObj ` is the concatenation of all objects

2.  `allObj.forEach` is looping through all elements (sub objects)

3.  Using ternary operator to assign the value

4.  If `obj._id` already exist in `preResult`, then assign `{...preResult[obj._id], ...obj}` (Concat  of pre value and new value)

5. Else assign new value `obj`
6. preResult is pair of obj._id and values
7. final result is the only values of preResult

Comment: @SumanMajhi Please edit your post, and explain your code there, instead of explaining in the comments.

Comment: @RickardElimää done

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Object1 = [
    {
        "_id": "62397fd1c517e11e05935cc7",
        "nickname": "uknowTest2",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-22T07:50:41.769Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "623824ccd1164bb8d9cc2521",
        "nickname": "qnvvzjrh",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-21T07:10:04.888Z",
        "animalCount": 1
    }
];

var Object2 = [
    {
        "_id": "62397fd1c517e11e05935cc7",
        "data": 36
    },
    {
        "_id": "623824ccd1164bb8d9cc2521",
        "data": 542717
    }
];

var Object3 = [
    {
        "_id": "62397fd1c517e11e05935cc7",
        "data2": 133111
    },
    {
        "_id": "623824ccd1164bb8d9cc2521",
        "data2": 540517
    }
];
let result = [...Object1];

let temp = [...result];
Object2.map(val=>{
  result.map((val2,index)=>{
    if(val2._id===val._id){
      val2 = {...val2,...val};
      temp[index] = val2
    }
  })
})
result = [...temp];
Object3.map(val=>{
  result.map((val2,index)=>{
    if(val2._id===val._id){
      val2 = {...val2,...val};
      temp[index] = val2
    }
  })
})
console.log(temp)
```